# Select a block of text via VS Code API

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I select/highlight a block of text by two different `vscode.Position`s via **VS Code API**?

[image]

Comment: create a `vscode.Selection` and assign it in an array to the `editor.selections`

Comment: As rioV8 said you have the anchor and active `Position`s of the selection.  Put those into a `new Selection(postions here)` and then `editor.selections = [your new selection].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create the two [Position](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Position) objects:

```js
const pos1 = new vscode.Position(line1, col1);
const pos2 = new vscode.Position(line2, col2);
```

Second, you create a [Selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Selection) using `pos1` as the anchor position, and `pos2` as the active position:

```js
const sel = new vscode.Selection(pos1, pos2)
```

Third, you assign an array containing that selection to the `selections` of the currently active [TextEditor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor):

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

editor.selections = [sel];
```